# Pass matlab size matrix to java

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, matrix

How can I pass a MATLAB result `s` like shown below to a Java method `JSize()`

```
s = size(oImage)

s =

91   121     3
```

Comment: Do you want to compute the size of each dimension in a multi-dimensional matrix in Java, or do you simply want to pass a 3 element array to a method in Java?  This is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you would need to know how many dimensions your array has.  Because this looks like an image, I'm going to assume that you'll expect a 3D array.

Because Java considers multidimensional arrays as an array of arrays, it isn't as dynamic as MATLAB where you can simply figure out how many dimensions there are by just checking the length of the `size` vector.

Assuming that your matrix is **not jagged**, you can determine how many rows you have by:

```
int rows = oImage.length;
```

If you want to determine how many columns there are, you can use any of the rows in your matrix and obtain its length:

```
int cols = oImage[0].length;
```

If you want to see how many elements there are in each 2D location in your matrix, you would just access any column in any row you specify and get its length.  In our case, let's stick with `oImage[0]`:

```
int dim = oImage[0][0].length;
```

Therefore, you could write a Java method that could return this as an array of elements similar to `size` in MATLAB:

```
public int[] JSize(int[][][] oImage) {
    return new int[] {oImage.length, oImage[0].length, oImage[0][0].length};
}
```

---

Remember, Java has the capacity of declaring jagged multi-dimensional arrays.  This means that each row in your 2D matrix **does not necessarily** have to have the same number of elements like what you would see in a matrix.  If you have a multi-dimensional array in Java that follows the above model, then the above code wlll work.